# Multiple process to catch uncaught exception?

Tags: android, multithreading, process, exception

I am developing a module that will be installed on multiple app. On of our client expressed concern about the potential of our module crashing making his app crash. I want to find a way to catch all uncaught exceptions that my module can throw. The module is composed of a `service` and 2-3 `activities` who have very little communication with the main app.

To catch those exceptions thrown by a handful of classes, and only those classes, what whould be the best option ? I have considered using `Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler` which catch all exception thrown by a thread and putting all thoses classes in a separate process (with the `android:process` attribute), but I was told that using multiple processes can impact performance and battery usage. Is it possible to start a service and multiple activities in a separate thread without having to rewrite them all ?

Comment: You can write in Application onCreate()

Comment: No I cannot, I am working on a separate module and do not have access to the Application. Futhermore this would catch all uncaugth exception when I onlu want those thrown by 2 or 3 components.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement an uncaught exception handler from your library. It will handle the uncaught exceptions that got triggered from threads started from your library.
Don't forget to pass it to the `DefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler`.
If the app implemented its own `UncaughtExceptionHandler` it will handle it as well.